# Difference between apache:velocity 1.6.4 and org.apache.velocity:velocity-engine-core 2.3

Tags: maven-plugin, velocity

Can anyone please suggest, what dependencies need to be modified while moving from apache:velocity 1.6.4 to org.apache.velocity:velocity-engine-core 2.3 ?
and also please explain, what are the major changes are brought under velocity-engine-core 2.3 with respect to velocity 1.6.4

Answer (score 1):

You can read [Upgrading](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.3/upgrading.html) sections from bottom to top.